# How can I render a HTML file with side js files using express in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a index.html file, which i want to send, using

`` app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(`${__dirname}/index.html`)
}); ``

Also, I have some js files in this directory, which I want to use in HTML by

`<script src="./js/index.js"></script>`

So, how can I make these js files accessible in HTML?

Comment: With https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use what @fedeteka suggested.

```
app.use('/js', express.static('js'));
```

The example above basically makes any file in the `js` folder to be accessed by the `/js` path. For example, if you have your file tree set up like

```
Main Folder
-----js
----------script.js
----------another.js
----------asmanyasyouwant.js
```

These files can be accessed by going to `localhost:{yourport}/js/script.js` or `localhost:{yourport}/js/another.js`, etc.

If you set it up this way, you can have

```
<script src="/js/index.js"></script>
```

as long as you have a file called `index.js` in the js folder.